# has_many through relationship set as array of ids with an extra column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a "n to n" relationship between `activity_summaries` and `gears`.

```
#ActivitySummary
has_many :activity_summaries_gears
has_many :gear_furnished, -> { where(activity_summaries_gears: {furnished: true}) }, through: :activity_summaries_gear, source: :gear
has_many :gear_advised, -> { where(activity_summaries_gears: {furnished: false}) }, through: :activity_summaries_gear, source: :gear

#active_summaries/_form
<%= check_box_tag 'activity_summary[gear_furnished_ids][]', gear.id,
@execution_summary.gear_furnished.include?(gear) %>
<%= check_box_tag 'activity_summary[gear_advised_ids][]', gear.id,
@execution_summary.gear_advised.include?(gear) %>
```

And my relationship table has an extra column furnished.

I would like to set `furnished` to true if the association is created with `gear_furnished` and false if it is created with `gear_advised`.

I create the relation in my `ActivitySummary` controller with an array `furnished_gear_ids` and an array `advised_gear_ids`.

Comment: Have you tried overriding gear_furnished_ids and gear_advised_ids setters in your execution summary model ?